# Does the main method get an initialized array or are the strings in the command line enter directly in to the parameter as I type?

Tags: java, arrays, parameters, command-line-arguments, program-entry-point

For example, if I want to print an array length, I can not do that:

```
public class Test{
     public static void main(String [] args){
          System.out.println(worngParam({"first", "second", "ect"}));
     }
     public static int worngParam(String [] strings){
          return strings.length;
     }
}
```

This is an error!

The first two lines in main must be

```
String [] strings = {"first", "second", "ect"};
System.out.println(worngParam(strings));
```

But even so I can do that:

```
System.out.println(args.length);//If of course args is not empty
```

My question is how does the parameter get into the main method?

Although any method can accept a constant variabls such as `3, "word", 'a'`. But she can not get an initialization of an array like this `{1,8}` or `{"word2", "word3"}`

Comment: You have to pass `new String[] {"first", "second", "ect"}` instead of `{"first", "second", "ect"}` when calling a method.

Comment: `{ "first", "second" }` is called an array initializer, and is shorthand for `new String[] { "first", "second" }`. The thing is, **omitting the `new String[]` part is only allowed at the time of declaration of the array**.

Comment: The `args` string array is constructed by the JVM and passed to your `main(String[])` method upon start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposed you run your java class file like this

```
javac Test.java
java -cp . Test firstParam secondParam thirdParam
```

Then in your main method args will have a value like

```
args = new String[]{"firstParam", "secondParam", "thirdParam"};
```